# sudden error of QLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services

I have been working on an existing laravel API project where they always have a sudden error of

```
 local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution at /var/www/html/web/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:31)
[stacktrace]
```

sometimes it goes away by restarting the AWS instance or other times it remains there. however, the problem is that it is a running website why this problem is occurring and resolves itself and the website has been down for many hours because of this error and this time restarting the AWS instance doesn't even help.

I can access the database via workbench but can't access it from there website.

what is going on?

Comment: Seems like a DNS issue.

Comment: @tadman any idea how do i fix this? so that i don't encourter this problem again?

Comment: If you have a predictable IP for that service, use that instead of the DNS name which can intermittently flake out. If the IP may change without warning you're sort of stuck with this, but then you have to expect that your connections to the server might get cut as well. If you're using RDS do they give any guarantees about that?

Comment: We are also on AWS and have never experienced any issues like this. Have you changed the default DNS resolution servers? Also is the database you are accessing using a DNS entry which is outside AWS (i.e. not under Route53)

Comment: @apokryfos we have the main entry inside the Route53 but not our subdomain entry in 53.i have applied an elastic ip to my subdomain so that it never changes from now on.
i am now getting another This site can’t be reached, i can see port 80 and 443 are closed, even though they are applied in security inbound and outbound rule.

for A record i did my subdomain instance id, and i for my subdomain NS for records i copied the root website records.

Comment: @tadman, you are right its kind of a DNS issue which is chasing me, my subdomains don't laod now i added now subdomain entries to my Route S3. for A records i added subdomain and its instance IP address and for NS record i copied the root ns records which i see kind of private records.. but it doesn't resolve the problem. any help would be really appreciated i have spent countless hours into this.

Comment: @tadman for this subdomain instance, i can only see port 22 is opened for SSH but 80, 8080, 443 all are closed but on aws security policies they are allowed in inbound and outbound rules

Comment: If it's a DNS configuration issue you may want to ask on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) as that's not usually a programming problem but a configuration one.